# Define transformation $T([x \space \space y\space \space z]^T) = [xy\space\space\space xz]^T$. Is it true that $dim(ker(T)) = 2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So again, the task is

> Consider map $T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ defined by $$ T\bigr(\begin{bmatrix}
> x & y & z
> \end{bmatrix}^T \bigr) = \begin{bmatrix}
> xy & xz
> \end{bmatrix}^T$$
>
> Evaluate dim(ker(T))

The solution given by the textbook I'm reading:

[image]

He says

> "The entries of the vector $\bf x$ such that $T(\mathbf x) = \bf O$ gives $x=0$, $y=r$, and $z=s$."

What about vector $\bf x$ such that

$$ \mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}
c\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} $$

where $c ≠ 0$? If I am not missing anything, the author fails to mention that case.

So the correct kernel for $T$ must be

$$ker(T) = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & y & z
\end{pmatrix}^T \mid y,z \in \mathbb R \} \cup \{\begin{pmatrix}
c & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^T \mid c \in \mathbb R \}$$

And seems like in this case, $nullity(T) = 3$, instead of $2$.

So

**Question**

Is he correct? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: Yes, it was missed. I wonder if it was missed because if $T$ was linear (which it's not), then your answer implies $T$ is the zero transformation. Maybe that's why the author stopped short of considering that. Either way, it's a mistake.

Comment: You are correct about the kernel. However, $T$ is not linear, and the kernel is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, so it doesn’t really make sense to talk about the nullity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ isn't a linear map so talking about its "kernel" and a basis for that kernel is weird. As you see, $T(1,0,0) = T(0,1,0) = T(0,0,1) = 0$ so if $T$ were linear then $T(a,b,c) = 0$ for any $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

The zero-set of $T$ (I don't want to call it a kernel) is the set of all $(x,y,z)$ such that $xz = 0$ and $xy = 0$. We can write this as

$$ [(x = 0) \text{ or } (z = 0)] \text{ and } [(x = 0) \text{ or } (y = 0)] = (x = 0) \text{ or } (y = 0 \text{ and } z = 0). $$

So we can see that the zero set is the union of the $yz$-plane and the $x$-axis. Namely:
$$ \{(x,y,z) : T(x,y,z) = 0\} = \{(0,y,z) : y, z \in \mathbb R\} \cup \{(x,0,0) : x \in \mathbb R\}. $$

We can't expect this to be a linear subspace because $T$ isn't linear. Since it is the union of a plane (2-dimensional) and a line (1-dimensional) it doesn't have a well defined "dimension" either.